# Employer changed agreed hourly rate after starting the job. What to do?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I was told in an email that the M-F hourly rate is $10 and weekend rate is $11.  At the interview I was told $10.  (The interviewer didn't mention a difference for weekends).  I accepted the position.

I did 7 hours of training and an 8 hour shift both during the week (this week).

Today I received a letter in the mail that my rate is $9.  I called my supervisor and she said the rate is $9.  Even though she told me $10!  She said she would look into it with HR.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have an offer letter that lists the salary you were promised?  If not, it's basically your word against there's.

Comment: Are you going to quit if its only 9?  If so then quit

Comment: _I was told in an email that the M-F hourly rate is $10_ Forward that e-mail to your supervisor.

Comment: Is there any sort of contract, or is this at will?

Comment: At will employment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you **now wait a bit for your supervisor to consult with HR**, chances are they just made a mistake and it can be easily fixed without making a big deal out of it.

If they insist that the rate is lower than you negotiated, I suggest you **search for that email where you were offered such rate and use it to back up your claims**. Perhaps HR was unaware of this specific rate you agreed on your contract.

This sort of things (salary, rates, etc.) are most of the times also specified in your **contract**, so I suggest you **check that one also** to be sure.

If after all of this they refuse to give you the rate you were offered in the beginning then I am afraid that you will have to decide if it is worth to continue working there or look for other jobs where they keep their word on what they offer. If it comes up to this, I also suggest you land a new offer *before* quitting for your safety and convenience.

Comment: I forwarded a copy of the rate to my supervisor and HR.  It's just upsetting that I had to go thru a physical and training before starting this job.  Thank you for your advice

Comment: I resigned today after they said it was a miscommunication and would not negotiate at all

Comment: @NicoleHalajian well, glad to hear you sorted it out, for the next time I suggest you try to get them give you a more explicit offer. Hope you can find a new job soon, I hope you landed one before quitting as suggested